# Impact Oracle DB by frequently creation and Drop of tables

Tags: oracle, database-design

I have a use case where we need to store some data for a specific period(lets say, 10k rows for 5 mins) and since data is huge so can`t store in Java Memory. Please help me to understand which one is the best approach from following and why?

1. Create a permanent table and introduce a column, which will help me to fetch and drop the rows as per the session.
2. Create multiple temporary table for each session and drop just after the process.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Its sound like you just need to make use of GTTs, please check out the below documentation for the same, you dont need to worry about truncating or dropping the table as data will be stored only till the session lasts.

[Documentation](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables#:%7E:text=Discussed%20here.-,Creation%20of%20Global%20Temporary%20Tables,just%20for%20the%20current%20transaction.)